# Как в Phpstorm подсвечивать синтаксис в блоке?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Есть проект, в котором много файлов с расширением .frm (роли, по сути, не играет).
Сам файл представляет собой xml разметку.
В некоторых тегах, встречаются вставки кода на sql заключенные в **<[data[ .. ]]**.
Проблема в том, что код в блоке **<[data[ .. ]]** воспринимается как обычный текст, а значит подсветка синтаксиса к нему не применяется. Также как и форматирование кода (все выравнивается в один столбец).
В настройках сделал ассоциацию для *.frm подсвечивать как php код.

Возможно ли как-то заставить phpstorm подсвечивать и форматировать код внутри этого тега как sql ( или любой другой) код, независимо от кода, который вне тега?

p.s. переименовывать файлы, в стиле *.frm.sql или иначе нельзя.
p.s.s. версия среды 2019 года.

Пример кода.

```xml
<component .. >
    <set .. >
        <[data[
            select * from dd
        ]]>
    </set>
</component>
```